# Is there a function for extracting numbers from a string

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I'm trying to find out how to get numbers that are in a string.

I tried the Number(string) function but it returns me a "NaN" ...

For example :

```
let str = "MyString(50)";

/*Function that return "NaN"*/
let numbers = Number(str);

console.log(numbers);


//Output expected : 50
//Output if get : 50
```

Do anyone has an idea why "Number" isn't returning me the right value or another way to do it ?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: `Number` will try to convert *the whole string* as a number, it doesn't parse for the first occurrence of numerics. Since `MyString` is not a number at all, you get NaN. It makes sense, what if you had `"My 4 number 2"` - do you expect `4`, `2`, or `42`? The three are equally likely.

Comment: Ok, i just understood the correct `Number` function use.
In this cas i'm excpecting `50` but if get `[5,0]` i'll work with that.
Thanks !

Comment: what all you number can include ? is it always integer or it can have floats too ? can there be cases like `mystring123some123` what will be desired output for such cases ?

Comment: No the it can only be like `string(140)` no separated numbers ... But an answer using a regexp seems to be the one that fits with my needs.
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.match` with a regex to filter out numbers, and use `unary +` or `Number(str)` or `parseInt` to get the number

```js
let str = "MyString(50)";

let numbers = +str.match(/\d+/);

console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with regexp, i'll look how it work.
If you have a good doc about it i'll be happy to read it.
Thanks for this answer

Comment: here's the explanation for regex used https://regex101.com/r/U9OTuO/1 for more [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Thanks for that precious help !

Answer (score 1):

The `match` regular expression operation is used to get number.

```js
 var str = "MyString(50)"; 
 var matches = str.match(/(\d+)/);
 
 console.log(matches[0]);
```

Refer this link to know about regular expression link [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions].

Comment: Thanks I'll use RegExp for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here a more comprehensive regex to detect all kinds of numbers in a string:

/ `0[bB][01]+` | `0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+` | `[+-]?` `(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+\.?)` `(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?` /g;

```
   binary   |       hex         | sign?      int/float       exponential part?
```

```js
const matchNumbers = /0[bB][01]+|0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+|[+-]?(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+\.?)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?/g;

let str = `
Let      -1
us       +2.
start    -3.3
and      +.4
list     -5e-5
some     +6e6
number   0x12345
formats  0b10101  
`;

console.log("the string", str);

const matches = str.match(matchNumbers);

console.log("the matches", matches);

const numbers = matches.map(Number);

console.log("the numbers", numbers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```